# Measure Theory - finite measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $E,F \in\mathcal{M}$. Define $E \equiv F$ if  $\mu(E\,\Delta\, F)=0$. Show that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{M}$. I have already shown reflexive and symmetry properties, but stucked in proving transitivity. Can anyone help me? Also I obtained that if $\mu(E\,\Delta\, F)=0$, then $\mu(E)=\mu(F)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. let $G$ be the third set. Then: $$E \Delta G \subseteq (E \Delta F) \cup (F \Delta G)$$
Draw a Venn diagram to convince yourself of that. Then: $$\mu(E \Delta G) \leq \mu((E \Delta F) \cup (F \Delta G)) \leq \mu(E \Delta F) + \mu(F \Delta G) = 0+0 = 0$$
Hence $\mu(E \Delta G) = 0$.